# Replace E-Mails in Webform 8 when dumping to test stage

Tags: webforms, emails, staging

We sanititze our dumps from production to test so that no newsletter subscriptions, form submissions or ohter things get into the test environement and bad things happen :D

Is there a simple way to get the E-Mails configured in webforms automatically replaced too?
As the number of forms and drupal sites will grow (100+), its a bit hard to handle with drush or sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link covers `drush sql:sanitize`, including how to extend it with your own custom sanitizations: https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-9-sanitising-data-drush

Comment: A good point. Already use drush sql:sanitize. Have to check out how to extend it and replace the e-mails in the config blobs.